# App crashes in viewForHeaderInSection:

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have have a tableview integrated in my app. The code is like this

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [sortedDates count];
}

- (nullable UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    EventHeaderView *headerView = (EventHeaderView *)[tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:@"eventHeader"];
    if(headerView == nil) {
        headerView = [[EventHeaderView alloc] initWithReuseIdentifier:@"eventHeader"];
    }

    NSString *date = [sortedDates objectAtIndex:section]; **// app crashes here**
    NSString *formatHeaderStr = [NSDate stringFromDate:[NSDate dateFromString:date withFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"] withFormat:@"EE, MMMM dd yyyy"];
    [headerView.dateLbl setText:formatHeaderStr];
    [headerView.addEventBtn setTag:(section+1)*100];
    [headerView.addEventBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(addEventBtnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [headerView layoutSubviews];
    return headerView;
}
```

The number of sections return 'sortedDates' count but still viewForHeader crashes on [sortedDates objectAtIndex:section]. It happens at other places in my code as well.

I do not understand how to fix such issues. There is very small delay in these methods being getting called one after the other but still the array seems to be empty when it reaches the viewForHeader methods.

Kindly help.

Comment: May be your `sortedDates` does not have the `index` from which you are trying to pick the `date`.

Comment: post data of sortedDates array...

Comment: Also show UITableView methods like `numberOfRowsInSection` and
`cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: Try this, NSString *date = sortedDates[section];

Comment: sortedDates array keeps changing but the method numberOfSections is called before viewForHeader method. If the method is returning 4 that means there are 4 sections. Why my app is crashing because of array not having enough values.

Answer (score 1):

Use this for getting value from `sortedDates`.

```
NSString *date = [sortedDates objectAtIndex:section-1];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using objectAtIndex method make sure that your array has that many objects in it.So in your case just check

```
if (section >= 0 && section < [sortedArray count])
{
    NSString *date = [sortedDates objectAtIndex:section];
}
```

Also check if the sortedDate object is not released accidentally.